# conditional ifs for multiple return cases

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have the following condition a class and a method

```
public class ReturnParameter
   {
      public string v1 {get; set;} 
      public string v2 {get; set;} 
      public string v3 {get; set;} 
   }


  public string RideCombination(ReturnParameter retor)
  {
     var v1 =  retor.v1;
     var v2 =  retor.v2;
     var v3 =  retor.v3;


     // case 1
     if(v1 == "A" && v2 == "b" && v3 == "C" ) 
       return  "valid 1 "

     // case 2
     if(v1 == "C" && v2 == "A" && v3 == "C" ) 
       return  "valid 2 "

    // case 3
     if(v1 == "D" && v2 == "T" && v3 == "C" ) 
       return  "valid 3 "

   // case 4
     if(v1 == "A" && v2 == "B" && v3 == "C" ) 
       return  "valid 4 "

  }
```

suppose I have 20 conditions I will have to 20 ifs to return 20 different combinations, is there any way I can eliminate multiple conditions without having to do one by one?

Comment: Static dictionary Add("AbC", "valid1"), for example. Concatenate input strings and then return result of lookup

Comment: Since your question is also tagged design patterns, I would suggest reading up on strategy pattern as well. In most cases a simple lookup should suffice though

Comment: @zzxyz That doesn't handle blank values very well.

Comment: @mjwills - yeah, concatenating the strings is a bad idea if they aren't all single character values.  I assumed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dictionary of values tuple and return value:

```
var mapping = new Dictionary<(string, string, string), string>
{
    [("A", "b", "C")] = "valid 1",
    // ...
};

if (mapping.TryGetValue((retor.v1, retor.v2, retor.v3), out var result))
{
    return result;
}
else
{
    // when none match...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd [use a switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#constant-pattern):

```
public string RideCombination(ReturnParameter retor)
{
    switch ($"{retor.v1}{retor.v2}{retor.v3}")
    {
        case "AbC":
            return "valid 1 ";
        case "CAC":
            return "valid 2 ";
        case "DTC":
            return "valid 3 ";
        case "ABC":
            return "valid 4 ";
        default:
            return "no match!";
    }
}
```

or [a Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) for constant-time lookup:

```
Dictionary<string, string> lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "AbC", "valid 1 "},
    { "CAC", "valid 2 "},
    { "DTC", "valid 3 "},
    { "ABC", "valid 4 "}
};
return lookup[$"{retor.v1}{retor.v2}{retor.v3}"];
```

Comment: This is only valid if all of the strings are single characters, which isn't necessarily the case in the real data.

Comment: @Servy If I tried to code for every case, I'd never have a sufficient answer.  I used the data that the OP provided.

Comment: You can, and should, write the code to work for any valid data, rather than only writing a solution that works for one example provided and fails in all sorts of others.  You absolutely can solve this problem when the values can be any type of string.  After all, the code in the question does so.

Comment: @Servy Did you read the question?  The class definition is there.  You're being pedantic.

Comment: Yes, I did read the question.  Where in the question does it say that all of the string values are always one character long?  If you consider "writing a program that produces valid output" pedantic, then I guess I'm pedantic.  The alternative is writing a program that doesn't work.

Comment: The dictionary approach may throw a `KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: Do you read what I've written because it will work with any size of string @Servy

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Thanks for the pointer.  I'm used to scripting languages where I'd just get null instead.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 how would the code differentiates between ("abc", "", "") and ("ab", "", "c")?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 No, it will not.  Not every unique combination of strings produces a unique string when concatenated together.  "AA, "A", "A, and "A", "AA", "A" both produce the same concatenated string, despite being different collections of strings.  There are innumerable such combinations of collections of strings that produce the same value, despite being different collections of strings.

Comment: @Servy That is a different argument than you had before.  Yes, if they depend on all of the values being evaluated separately, my solution does not work to their need, but I made my solution according to their question.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 No, it's not a different argument.  I stated that your solution provides the wrong value for possible valid inputs, and you said that you didn't care because the one example provided in the question works, and that's all that matters, according to you.  The question asks to provide a given output for a given combination of three strings, not to provide a given output for a given single string, as you have done.  The two are different.  Your solution doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: `I'm used to scripting languages where I'd just get null instead.` Consider using `TryGetValue`.

Comment: the approach is good but a part of it was not made clearly which is sinister syntax error